# Tabbar disappears after segue

Tags: ios, tabbar

Hi guys I have a Main Navigation Controller and a Tab Bar Controller, I have 4 Viewcontrollers and everything works fine. Now I have to open a ViewController from a Button Push Segue, the problem is that the Tabbar disappears once I do that. Is there a simple solution to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, the order has to be reversed. TabBar, then NavigationBar. And you inversed it.

Comment: This is because your `TabBarController` is in a navigation controller. Remove the `TabBarController` from navigation controller and add each tab item viewcontrollers inside navigation controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `TabBarController` as `InitialViewController` and Embed your viewcontrollers with `UINavigationController`. This will not hide your `Tabbar` from bottom.